# VS 2022 errors ENC0020, ENC0021 even though code changes were made prior to starting debug session

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I have a solution with multiple projects, including:  2 Class Libraries, 1 REST API server, 1 Web server, 2 REST API clients.  I made a change in the code underneath REST API server - I changed a function to async, and added await to the calls to it.

I made the code changes while NOT debugging - it was not in run mode.  I then cleaned the entire solution and did a rebuild all.  However, when I press Run to debug, I get the following errors.

HOWEVER - the code runs.  I can set breakpoints and step through the new code I added, it executes.  No idea why it is showing the errors.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   ENC0020 Renaming method requires restarting the application.    RESTServer  E:\Data\dotNetDev\ea\RESTServer\RESTServer\Models\AccountModel.cs   231 Active
Error   ENC0021 Adding parameter requires restarting the application.   .Core   E:\Data\dotNetDev\ea\RESTServer\.Core\System-email.cs   45  Active
Error   ENC0021 Adding await expression requires restarting the application.    RESTServer  E:\Data\dotNetDev\ea\RESTServer\RESTServer\Controllers\AccountController.cs 161 Active
Error   ENC0021 Adding await expression requires restarting the application.    RESTServer  E:\Data\dotNetDev\ea\RESTServer\RESTServer\Controllers\AccountController.cs 212 Active
Error   ENC0021 Adding await expression requires restarting the application.    RESTServer  E:\Data\dotNetDev\ea\RESTServer\RESTServer\Controllers\AccountController.cs 260 Active
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's look like a bug introduced in VS 2022 17.1.3 and 17.1.4, nothing to do except restart VS.

Comment: I can confirm this. Sometimes double-clicking the error in Error List clears it, but sometimes you have to restart your entire IDE. That is very bad UX for an IDE. However, if you have restarted the application, builds can still succeed and you can continue working without restarting VS 2022.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem with version 17.0.6 and I updated version 17.3.4 now its fine.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently closing and relaunching Visual Studio 2022 solved the problem.

Comment: Yes but it comes back again and again.. anyone knows if this is reported as a bug? Link to that, if so? Cant find anything about it

Answer (score 0):

A Rebuild of the Solution worked for me and removed the error.

I suspect something was stuck in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per the accepted answer, it seems to be a bug. But builds can still succeed, so that you can continue developing without having to restart the entire IDE.

The error may stay shown in the Error List but not be an actual error, as long as you have fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was due to code error in "Razor view". I accidently deleted first line in razor view @model xxxx and started receiving lots of repeated error messages (one error for each use of Model.xx)

Error   ENC0020 Renaming method requires restarting the application.

double click the error and review opened razor file for code issues.